# tmlib.jsのManagerSceneによるシーンの遷移先の指定とパラメータの受け渡しについて

Tags: javascript, tmlib.js

tm.scene.ManagerSceneによるシーンの遷移先とパラメータの受け渡しについて教えてください。

先にサンプルを貼ります。
[runstant: ManagerSceneのサンプル](http://goo.gl/GwvZ77)

シーンの切り替え順番をManagerSceneの初期化時に指定した順ではなく特定のシーンへ遷移させたいです。

またその際に遷移元からパラメータを渡し、遷移先のシーンで受け取ることは可能ですか？

サンプルのコメントにも軽く書いていますが例えばthis.app.popScene()の引数で渡すようなイメージです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サンプルを作りました! -> runstant: http://goo.gl/H7TcpW
極力個々のシーンが独立するような作りになっています.

シーンの構成は,

- ManagerScene

  - TitleScene
  - Stage1Scene
  - Stage2Scene
  - ResultScene

となっており.

- TitleScene -> **Stage1Scene** -> ResultScene
- TitleScene -> **Stage2Scene** -> ResultScene

の２パターンの遷移をするようになっております.

方法についてですが, nextLabel と nextArguments を使います.

### nextLabel

シーンに nextLabel を設定することで ManagerScene で設定した nextLabel を上書きすることができます.

サンプルでは50行目あたりで使っています.

```
    this.button1.onpointingstart = function() {
        // nextLabel で飛び先変更できますよ♪
        this.nextLabel = "stage1";
        this.app.popScene();
    }.bind(this);

    this.button2.onpointingstart = function() {
        this.nextLabel = "stage2";
        this.app.popScene();
    }.bind(this);
```

stage1 ボタンを選んだ場合は stage1 へ, stage2 ボタンを選んだ場合は stage2 へ
遷移しているのがわかるかと思います.

### nextArguments

これは次のシーンに渡す arguments を上書きすることができます.

サンプルの85行目あたりです.

```
    // ①: このパラメータを遷移先のシーンに受け渡したい
    // A. nextArguments ってやつで渡せますよ♪
    this.nextArguments = {
        score: this.score,
    };

    this.app.popScene();
```

ちゃんとリザルトシーンにスコアが渡っているのがわかるかと思います.

Comment: そのnextLabelって、ManagerSceneのgotoNextで参照されている(timlib.js 0.4.0では17720行目)みたいですが、ドキュメント上はManagerSceneにもSceneにも見当たりません。nextArgumentsに至ってはソースからも見つけられなかったんですが、どこで知れる情報なんでしょう？(単純にどう調べればいいのか、調べ方があるなら知りたいという興味本位です。)

Comment: ありがとうございます。このやり方ですっきり実現できそうです。
こんな方法あったんですね。
私の方でもドキュメント見ましたがまだドキュメントに書かれていない機能もある、ということでしょうか？

Comment: @fliedonion さん, 確かにご指摘の通り nextLabel と nextArguments はドキュメント上には表示されてないですね.

プロパティとしてではなく登録追加した場合のみ有効になるように作っていたため使っている docs generator がキャッチしなかったようです.

空プロパティとして追加してドキュメントを更新しておきましたmm
https://github.com/phi-jp/tmlib.js/commit/bc8be3949144bb668e92c62c20339202582f93f2
http://phi-jp.github.io/tmlib.js/docs/index.html#!/api/tm.app.Scene

Comment: @fliedonion さん, 連投失礼します.
今回の質問に関して, 自分のドキュメント更新漏れがあったので開発者である自分以外には nextLabel, nextArguments を使うという回答は難しかったかなと思います. すみません.
調べ方についてですが, tmlib.js の develop ブランチ https://github.com/phi-jp/tmlib.js を直接見るのが確実です.

Comment: @phi なんと、開発者さんでしたか（アドレス見れば明白ですね、気づきませんでしたすみません）。developブランチは参考にさせてもらいます。今回たまたま漏れた要素があったものの、ドキュメントページも全般的に検索がしやすくメソッドなどの名前もわかりやすかったです。

Comment: @fliedonion さん
いえいえー, なんか中身がっつり調べて返信してくれていたのですごい驚きました! ManagerScene 自体最近追加したクラスでして...
今回 halt さんがしてくれた質問に関しても問題意識があって, 以前は fliedonion さんが回答してくれた方法しかなかったのですが, それだと ManagerScene の良さが死んじゃうなと思い nextLabel, nextArguments を追加した次第です.

Answer (score 2):

*22:08 編集*

pushSceneを使用する例として、提示のサンプルを修正させてもらいました([こちら](http://goo.gl/zZQZ9B))

最初に現れるresult画面ではbackではなくて画面クリックで先に進んでください。
（変わったことがわかりやすい様にResultSceneにしてあります）
appオブジェクトで管理していますので、再び表示したい場合は runし直してください。

パラメータの方は、シーンを生成するときに直接渡して、initの方で使ってあげればいいのではないでしょうか。

例えば TestSceneはnameをうけとっていますよね？
これは

```
TestScene({name: "Geme3"});
```

の様にすれば渡せると思います。

テンプレート(?)の、ResultScene継承したシーンであれば

```
tm.define("InjectScene", {
    superClass: "tm.scene.ResultScene",

    init: function(param) {
        this.superInit();

        this.scoreLabel.text = param.score;
        this.bestLabel.text = param.best;
    },
    onpointingstart: function(){
        this.app.popScene();
    }
});
```

であれば、

```
InjectScene({ score: 100, best: 1000});
```

として渡すことができます。

なお、ResultSceneにはtimeLabelが見当たらなかった(WebStormでもscore, best, nextはあったのですが)ため、bestに変更しています。

パラメータは名前は揃っている必要はないですがわかりやすさのために併せて修正しています。

途中でシーンを登場させるには、pushSceneを行います。
これにより、現在のシーンの流れにシーンをpushしてあげることができます。

pushしたシーンでも必要が無くなったら自分自身をpopSceneでpopしてください。
今回例としたInjectSceneでは、クリックさせるとpopするようにしています。

http://phi-jp.github.io/tmlib.js/docs/index.html#!/api/tm.app.BaseApp-method-pushScene

```
this.app.pushScene(InjectScene({ score: 100, best: 1000}));
```

pushした画面にラベルが見えてしまっていますが、このあたりは別途調整が必要ですね。

---

追記

> で、例えばステージ1のシーン、ステージ2のシーンからも"result"という名前で呼び出せる方法があれば嬉しいな、と。 その際にステージ1、ステージ2で使用したスコアなどのパラメータも上手く渡せる方法もあればついでに知りたい、という経緯でした。

appや現在のシーンからManagerSceneにアクセスする方法があるのかもしれませんが、
例えば以下の様に

```
app.manager = MainScene();
app.replaceScene(app.manager );
```

appからMainSceneにアクセス可能にしておいて、

```
// ②: 決まった順じゃなく動的にresultへ飛ばしたい
this.app.manager.gotoScene("result");

// 例えばこんなイメージでresultシーンへ飛び、resultシーンでsceneParamを受け取る
// this.app.popScene("result", sceneParam);
```

というようにgotoSceneを使えば移動は可能です。

http://phi-jp.github.io/tmlib.js/docs/index.html#!/api/tm.app.BaseApp

パラメータはmanagerからとるようにすれば可能だとは思いますが、

オブジェクトにセットする形はシーンオブジェクトを取得する方法が思いつきませんでした。

[サンプル](http://goo.gl/FxskTI)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！  
色々調べて書いてもらえたようで大変ありがたいです。  
  
ただ実は書いてもらった内容で目的は達成できるのですがちょっとだけ過程が違いまして(これは私の質問の仕方がちょっと雑でしたね…)。  
  
サンプルで書いてもらっていたapp.injectedでのフラグ管理とpushSceneにInjectScene渡す方法でも十分実現できるのですがシーン数、フラグ数が増えると管理が大変かなぁと。  
なので出来るだけ遷移先のシーンクラスを直接指定せずに依存関係を減らしてあげれたらと思いました。  
  
具体的にはシーンの管理はtm.scene.ManagerSceneで一括で行えるようなので、例えばtm.scene.ResultSceneは"result"という名前で管理したい。  
で、例えばステージ1のシーン、ステージ2のシーンからも"result"という名前で呼び出せる方法があれば嬉しいな、と。  
その際にステージ1、ステージ2で使用したスコアなどのパラメータも上手く渡せる方法もあればついでに知りたい、という経緯でした。

Comment: @Halt 遷移について追記しました。パラメータを渡すのはAPIみるにManagerSceneからSceneを検索できるのかが不明だったので（ChildAtなどは期待していたものとはちがったようで）みつけられませんでした。managerの方に書き込んでおいてそれを取り出すのは可能だと思います。

Comment: @Halt 最初のサンプルのinjectedにあまり意味はありません。動的にとのことだったので、条件によって動作を変えた方がいいだろうという事と、TestSceneの方に書いてもGame1とGame2は別のインスタンスなので引き継がれないので適当にどこからでも見える位置に置いたというだけです。ManagerSceneにおいておきたいのであればscenesに追加しない形で置いておくという方法も取れます。scenesに追加してしまうとpopSceneなどが呼ばれるとそれが表示されてしまうのでそれが都合が悪い場合はscenesに置かないという手も選択肢もあります。

Comment: なるほど。サンプルの方法でapp.managerにシーン設定しておいて呼び出すという方法もあるのですね。
パラメータもapp.managerに受け渡し用のものを置いて読み書きすれば可能そうですね。

Comment: @Halt そうですね。グローバル変数っぽいのが嫌ですが…。phiさんの回答のやり方のほうが理想に近そうですね。

Comment: そうですね、グローバル変数っぽいのが多少気になってはいました。さきほどphiさんが提示してくれていたサンプルをしばらく触ってみましたが理想に近い形で出来そうでした。
flied-onionさんも色々調べてもらえていたようで大変ありがたかったです。ありがとうございました。